# How to Return proper JSON response to use Froala with Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, laravel

I am attempting to use the Froala Text Editor with Laravel 5.2.29. I have followed the documentation to setup freya, and it works great! Until I try to Upload something. I am able to upload files with no problem using a normal html file button, but for some reason the ajax request doesn't seem to reach my controller. I cannot figure out why.

Here is my JQuery code that is on the page with the editor (I used the Froala documentation to write this):

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $('#body, #excerpt').froalaEditor({
            toolbarButtons: ['undo', 'redo', 'html', '-', 'fontSize', 'paragraphFormat', 'align', 'quote', '|', 'formatOL', 'formatUL', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'underline', '|', 'insertLink', 'insertImage', 'insertVideo', 'insertFile', 'insertTable'],
            heightMin: 300,
            imageUploadParam: 'file',
            imageUploadMethod: 'POST',
            // Set the image upload URL.
            imageUploadURL: '/fileUpload/{{ $department->id }}/post',
            // Pass the department id
            imageUploadParams: {
                id: {{ $department->id }},
                froala: 'true'
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have created a test.php file with the following code to test it with the froala documentation method of solving this and it works:

```
<?php
// Generate response.
        $response = new StdClass;
        $response->link = "http://my.server/image.jpg";
        echo stripslashes(json_encode($response));

        ?>
```

But for some reason, laravel will not return a proper json response. The json response from that test.php file is `{"link":"http://my.server/image.jpg"}' when i navigate straight to it. But when I test it in the routes file (not even in the controller which doesn't work either), I make a route that looks like this:

```
Route::get('/test', function(){
        return stripslashes(response()->json(['link' => "http://my.server/image.jpg"])->content());
        // echo '{"link":"http://my.server/image.jpg"}';
    });
```

This returns `{"link":"http://my.server/image.jpg"}` which looks exactly the same to me. But when I have it return that after a POST request, it just says 'Something went wrong, Please try again.'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's your route for POST request?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte: The route is the imageUploadURL in the JQuery, but when I do a `php artisan route:list` I get: "|        | POST      | fileUpload/{id}/post                             |                                           | App\Http\Controllers\FileUploadsController@store                | web,manager |"

Comment: If your error is in your POST request, we need to see the code from your POST method. If you are using a POST to you "/test", you should change your code to `Route::any('/test', ...`.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte I changed the route to Route::any('/test', function(){} and changed the jquery to post to /test. It still is doing the same thing.

Comment: We need to the code from your controller

Comment: @FelippeDuarte currently I'm testing this by returning the link to an image that already exists, then I can handle the image upload. If I return a link that already exists with normal php, it works. But it doesn't through this route. This is the route with the function that should return the proper JSON: 

Route::any('/test', function(){
  return stripslashes(response()->json(['link' => "http://intrafile.ergon.corp/profilePhotos/bedford-joshua-2015.jpg"])->content());
 });

Comment: POST http://intranet.jb.ercorr.com/test 500 (Internal Server Error) When I try to upload the photo, I get this error in the developers console.

Comment: ahha! I don't know how to solve this, but it is probably lacking the token that is normally passed through with forms. Would that be it? If so, how would one pass the laravel token through the ajax request with this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Froala, but it looks like you can set additional POST data with the `imageUploadParams` property? If so, you would add `'_token': {!! csrf_token() !!}` to that section to pass the token along with the request.

Comment: Also, if you want to test out AJAX responses live, open up your browser's dev tools and look at the Network tab. From there, you should be able to see the server responses by clicking on individual requests. It's very useful for debugging.

Comment: @wunch You were absolutely correct! I might have had other problems at that point, but it is fully working now!

Answer (score 0):

There were several problems, but one of the most confusing (but should have been obvious) answers was to pass a csrf token as laravel requires. This meant to add `'_token': {!! csrf_token() !!}` to the `imageUploadParams` item in the jquery. I've done a full setup guide here: http://thelightmedia.net/blog/using-froala-to-upload-images-with-laravel-5-2